# mysql for getting record of current date with join

Tags: mysql

Anyone please help me whether my query is correct

```
SELECT *
FROM advt_answer ad
JOIN advt_question xx ON ad.Q_ID=xx.Q_ID
WHERE xx.id='anu'    
AND xx.Active='Y' and date(ad.Date)= CURDATE()
```

My Results are Empty even when the data's are present.
I have a question table and answers table seperately... Questions can be inserted by multiple users... 
So the result i want is Question uploaded by particular and answers that is inserted in today's date
My date field id datetime i.e, my value will be '2014-01-23 15:39:00'

Comment: You are looking for `xx.id = ''` and you're sure that such data exists in that column, so that other conditions are evaluated to true?

Comment: Can you please provide us with sample data present in table? Mabe create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if possible.

Comment: My date field id datetime i.e, my value will be '2014-01-23 15:39:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wehn your `date` field is of type `varchar`, and the value is not in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, then the comparison

```
date( ad.Date ) = CURDATE()
```

fails, though you think it is a matching date.
To make it compared correct, you have to convert it to *proper date format*.
You can do this by `str_to_date` function.

If your varchar date (`ad.Date`) value is `02/20/2014`, then

```
str_to_date( ad.Date, '%m/%d/%Y' ) = CURDATE()
```

will result a `true`.

Use proper date format string if it is not `'%m/%d/%Y'`.

And it is best to apply a `date` specific data types to store date and time values.